# Add Dynamic Nav Bar in one line with horizontal scroll bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, scroll, navbar

Hello Friend I'm Making Phonegap App for  (WindowsPhone, Android, IOS, BB7 & BB10) I want NavigationBar can contains more then five nav elements in One line with horizontal scrollable 
this is my html code for nav-bar(nav-bar data comes dynamically according to need of user)

```
<div id="customize_div_id" style="width:2000px;  >
  <div  onclick="customize_nav_scroll();"  data-role="navbar" >
    <ul   class="customize-item-class" id="customize_item_id"> 
    </ul>   
  </div>
```

I'm able to create Dynamic Nav-bar using this link [More than 5 items per line in jQuery Mobile navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161377/more-than-5-items-per-line-in-jquery-mobile-navbar)

But My Problem is that Only five nav item will show to the user rest of all are horizontally scrollable.I'm not able to scroll these item's I Follow some method which is provided in JQuery Docs

`.scrollLeft( value )`

`.scrollRight( value )`

`$.event.special.swipe.start`

`$.event.special.swipe.stop`

`$.event.special.swipe.handleSwipe`

I also Try below method with lot possibility But I didn't get desirable result

```
  function customize_nav_scroll(){ 

       var step = 1;
       var current = 0;
       var maximum = $("#customize_div_id div ul li").size();
       var visible = 2;
       var speed = 500;
       var liSize = 120;
       var height = 30;    
       var ulSize = liSize * maximum;
       var divSize = liSize * visible;


        $("#customize_div_id div").css("width",ulSize+"px");
        $("#customize_div_id div ").css("width", "auto").css("visibility",  "visible").css("overflow", "hidden").css("position", "relative");
        $("#customize_div_id div ul li").css("list-style","none").css("display","inline");
        $("#customize_div_id div ul ").css("width", ulSize+"px").css("left", -(current * liSize)).css("position", "absolute").css("white-space","nowrap").css("padding","-10px");

        $("#customize_div_id div").swipeleft(function(event){
          if(current + step < 0 || current + step > maximum - visible) {
             return; }
             else {
               current = current + step;
                $("#customize_div_id div ul").animate({left: -(liSize * current)}, speed, null);
                }
                  return false;
            });

      $("#customize_div_id div").swiperight(function(event){
          if(current - step < 0 || current - step > maximum - visible) {return; }
              else {
                 current = current - step;
                 $("#customize_div_id div ul").animate({left: -(liSize * current)}, speed, null);
                 }
                    return false;
              });      
            }
```

[image: My Navigation Bar Image]

Comment: check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974807/trying-to-prevent-jquerymobile-swipe-gesture-from-bubbling-but-its-not-working) and an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/atuttle/3TW64/embedded/result/). Its about scrollable navbar.

Comment: Have you considered just making it .draggable with axis x and constraint?

Comment: Thanks for Comment Mr. Omar and Mr. Stevemarvell.
whole day i tried what ever you suggest but these suggestion not working.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have time to test with phonegap now...but a simple overflow does not work?

On your container:

```
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: auto;
```

On your navbar:

```
width: 2000px;
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9t4c7/2/)

Just an idea.

I will test later in phonegap.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Willian Duarte. I had also try with what ever you suggest but it did not going to work in mobile device like BB7.

Comment: When ever i found prefect solution then i will like share with all of you.